# tomcat started but application not loading in browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8

Tomcat is started. But I am getting Page cant be find error in browser.

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

Browser

This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://172.22.68.60:8083 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Enable JMX -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="10001" rmiServerPortPlatform="10002" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="100000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" proxyName="nap11rh6as510"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
              resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
          connectionName="CN=tomcatdeploy,OU=Services,OU=SvcAccts,DC=Regulusgroup,DC=net"
         connectionPassword="Regulusgroup1"
         connectionURL="ldap://regulusgroup.net"
         userBase="DC=regulusgroup,DC=net"
         userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
         userSubtree="true"
         roleBase="OU=Processes,OU=SvcAccts,DC=regulusgroup,DC=net"
         roleName="cn"
         roleSearch="(Member={0})"
         roleSubtree="true"
         referrals="follow"
       />
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Catalina.out:

```
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.112 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Realm/Realm} Setting property 'debug' to '99' did not find a matching property.
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.266 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.266 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.267 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.267 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_74-b02
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat8
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat8
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.270 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.270 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.270 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms1024m
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.270 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xss240k
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dwebapp.logdir=/opt/tomcat8/logs
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dwebapp.conf=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dview2.configuration=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf/view2.properties
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.272 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dview2.log.configuration=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf/view2-logback.xml
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.272 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dt2services.log.configuration=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf/t2services-logback.xml
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.272 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dt2backgroundservices.log.configuration=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf/t2backgroundservices-logback.xml
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.279 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dtrackit.log.configuration=file:/opt/tomcat8/conf/trackit-logback.xml
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/tomcat8/conf/devTrustStore.jks
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/jmxremote.password
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/jmxremote.access
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat8/endorsed
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat8
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat8
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat8/temp
25-Jul-2017 23:27:53.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
25-Jul-2017 23:27:55.755 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.052 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.086 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8083]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8083]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more

25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.087 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.093 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.098 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more

25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.103 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 4809 ms
25-Jul-2017 23:27:56.249 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.createServer Unable to create the RMI registry for the Platform server using port 10001
 java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 10001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:112)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.createServer(JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:762)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: It's unclear. Please provide more information (tomcat configuration, logs, ...)

Comment: Check your tomcat start logs which will give good information

Comment: Updated log and server.xml. Can you check now.?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Tomcat uses a default port of 8080 to show HTTP content, so your URL http://172.22.68.60:8010 is probably wrong.  Have you tried http://172.22.68.60:8080 ?

Comment: I have modified the port as 8010. I tried changing the ports already.

Comment: No, you have an AJP connector port at 8010.  Your HTTP/1.1  connector port is at 8083.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I tried that too. Getting same error.

Comment: Do you have a firewall turned on, is it blocking port 8083?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other application using port 8080 before starting tomcat. If that's not the case than please paste server.xml and tomcat log.

**Try changing default and current port and also try killing tomcat service which is already running.**

- check whether you have not configured welcome page  Try adding
- http://172.22.68.60:8010/ApplicationName which you are deploying
  in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have started your tomcat.In windows,we start tomcat by run a executable file named startup.bat under /bin.

Comment: Yes I started the tomcat by running startup.sh file under bin